# Is there a work that lists Good qualities and defines how to attain them

Tags: islamic-philosophy

Is there a work that lists Good qualities like Taqwa, Haya, Sabr and defines and elaborates on how to attain them, in English. For example Purification of the Heart: Signs, Symptoms and Cures of the Spiritual Diseases of the Heart by Hamza Yusuf lists the diseases and then the cures for them, I'm looking for something similar but on good qualities.

Comment: Your question is too general, could you be more specific plz

Comment: the work Purification of the heart lists bad qualities like this,  Bukhl – Miserliness
~ Batar – Wantonness
~ Bughud – Hatred
~ Al Baghyu – Harming creation when there is no just cause
~ Madah – love of praise
~ Hasad – Envy. Then it goes through what causes these bad qualities to appear in a person after wards it lists the cures for these qualities. Is there a work like this but for good qualities, for example if i want to increase my sabr what are the steps i need to take.

Comment: Ibn al-Qayyim's works are great for this - Zaad al-Ma'd, Madarij as-Salikeen. Also check ibn Qudamah's Mukhtasar Minhaj al-Qasidin.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to read more these books:

- **Sufism & Good Character: Prophetic Guidance on the Spiritual Path** (Zafar Ahmad 'Uusmani)
- **Al-Adab Al-Mufrad** (Imam al Boukhâri). It's rather a collection of ahaadith. I will recommend you to read its English commentary : **Manners in Islam** (Al-Adab Al-Mufrad) - Imam Bukhari's Book of Muslim Morals and Manners (Translation by Maulana Khalid Khan Garhi; Rafiq Abdur Rahman)

You can find also some good ressources on:

- http://tasawwuf.org/
- http://www.sulaimanmoola.co.za/

Either you agree or not with Tassawuf, these Ulemah's speechs are full with reference to ahaadiths. It's really worth listening.